# date calculation with days rather than seconds

Tags: r, datetime, data.table, posixct

I have 2 columns:

```
date1           date2
2015-01-01      2015-01-31
2015-01-02      2015-01-31
2015-01-03      2015-01-31
2015-10-27      2015-08-31
```

I want to create new column `diff` based on `date1` and `date2`.

```
data[,diff := pmax(0, date2 - date1)]
```

The result I want is like:

```
date1           date2          diff
2015-01-01      2015-01-31     30
2015-01-02      2015-01-31     29
2015-01-03      2015-01-31     28
2015-10-27      2015-08-31     -57
```

However, I got this:

```
date1           date2          diff
2015-01-01      2015-01-31     2592000
2015-01-02      2015-01-31     2505600
2015-01-03      2015-01-31     2419200
2015-10-27      2015-08-31     0
```

The date calculation uses **seconds**. But, I want **days**.
Any help?

Comment: Can you just convert the seconds into days? `data$diff <- data$diff / 60 / 60 / 24`

Comment: The answer depends on the class of `date1` and `date2`. So, please, post your sample date using `dput()`. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that we need to change the negative values to 0 based on the usage of `max`, then replace `max` with `pmax`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, diff := pmax(0, date2-date1)]
data
#        date1      date2 diff
#1: 2015-01-01 2015-01-31   30
#2: 2015-01-02 2015-01-31   29
#3: 2015-01-03 2015-01-31   28
#4: 2015-10-27 2015-08-31    0
```

and if we are following the expected output

```
setDT(data)[, diff  := as.integer(date2-date1)]
data
#        date1      date2 diff
#1: 2015-01-01 2015-01-31   30
#2: 2015-01-02 2015-01-31   29
#3: 2015-01-03 2015-01-31   28
#4: 2015-10-27 2015-08-31  -57
```

#### Update

Based on the output, OP, got, we think it could be the based on the original dataset, one option is `difftime` where the `unit` argument forces the output to be in 'day'.

```
setDT(data)[, diff := pmax(0, difftime(date2,date1, units = 'day'))]
```

and for the second case

```
setDT(data)[, diff := as.integer(difftime(date2,date1, units = 'day'))]
```

OP may have got the output due to dates with a smaller difference which changes it to `sec` instead of `day`

#### Update2

The OP confirmed that the  'date' columns were `POSIXct`.  So, we can also convert it to `Date` and get the difference with `-`

```
data[, diff := as.integer(as.Date(date2) - as.Date(date1))]
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(date1 = structure(c(16436, 16437, 16438, 16735
), class = "Date"), date2 = structure(c(16466, 16466, 16466, 
16678), class = "Date")), .Names = c("date1", "date2"),
 row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I edit my question. `data[,diff := pmax(0, date2 - date1)]`. Still not work

Comment: @PeterChen It is working fine for me.  Could you update with the `dput` of the example

Comment: the dates calculate with `seconds`, not `days`. And what is `dput`. Sorry, I'm new with R

Comment: @PeterChen  I believe it is based on not the 4 rows mentioned in the example.  Can you try on the 'data' in my post?  Also, I updated with `difftime`

Comment: FYI: it works fine for me as well, even with columns date1 and date2 as factors.

Comment: @akrun your update works. Awesome. I don't know why R calculates with `seconds`. It's weird.

Comment: @PeterChen  Are you sure that the Date columns are `Date` class?  I am using R 3.3.3 with data.table_1.10.4

Comment: @user2100721  Thanks, it is `units`, though the `unit` also worked without any error/warning

Comment: @akrun `$ date1 : POSIXct, format: "2015-01-01"...` and `$ date2 : POSIXct, format: "2015-01-31...`

Comment: @PeterChen  Okay, that is the reason, you got output in seconds.  I thought, you were having 'Date' class. Anyway `difftime` works in these cases or another option is `data[, diff := as.integer(as.Date(date2) - as.Date(date1))]`

Comment: @akrun I think arguments also have partial matching property. For that reason, it worked there.

Comment: @akrun I think you should add `data[, diff := as.integer(as.Date(date2) - as.Date(date1))]` in your answer. it works. Awesome.

Answer (score 2):

The difference gets you seconds because you probably have objects representing *times* not *dates* in your data.

If your data is really only ever going to deal with dates, ie whole days, use the provided `Date` class. Example:

```
data = data.frame(
   date1=as.Date(c("2015-01-01","2015-01-02","2015-10-27")),
   date2 = as.Date(c("2015-01-31","2015-01-31","2015-08-31")))
```

Then:

```
> data$diff = data$date2 - data$date1
> data
       date1      date2     diff
1 2015-01-01 2015-01-31  30 days
2 2015-01-02 2015-01-31  29 days
3 2015-10-27 2015-08-31 -57 days
>
```